# MySQL Between issue not working with Unix Time Stamps

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, between

I am currently storing dates as Unix Time Stamps in an INT(10) column in a mysql version 4.0.8 db (MyISAM engine).

I query these dates to extract records between a date range using the following SQL:

```
$sql = "SELECT `users`.`real_name`, `users`.`user_value`, `clients`.`client_name`, `clients`.`client_stars`, `timing`.`start_date`, `timing`.`end_date`, `projects`.`project_name`
    from timing
    LEFT JOIN users on (users.id = timing.user_id)
    LEFT JOIN clients on (clients.id = timing.client_id)
    LEFT JOIN projects on (projects.project_id = timing.project_id)
    WHERE start_date BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date";
```

I am using PDO, hence the params.

I am 100% sure the :start_date and :end_date vars are correct in all cases as I have checked these. Also start_date is not ambiguous and there are no warnings/notices regarding this query.

My problem is that I do not get the rows expected. If I ask for rows between Midnight 2013/11/14 and Midnight 2013/11/15, the expectation is ONLY results from the 14th. However, rows from the 15th are also passed - but not all of them.

I also just tested between 1384473600 and 1384473600 - which is between midnight today and midnight today (as in the same timestamp).

The rows returned should be 0, yet it has returned all rows from today (for instance the first row returned has a start_date value of 1384524193)!

Have I missed something about how the between operator works in mySQL? How can it return rows when the min and max are the same?

I have tested and tested, and nearly every time I make a query, rows are returned that are ABOVE the specified between ceiling.

What is going wrong?

Comment: have you tried this: `WHERE start_date >= :start_date AND start_data <= :end_date` ?

Answer (score 0):

`BETWEEN` is a notoriously bad way to match dates and timestamps, because it's inclusive of both ends of the range.

This may work better for you

```
    WHERE start_date >= :start_date
      AND start_date <  :end_date + 86400
```

The magic number `86400` is the number of seconds in a day. This selects all start_date values between midnight on the :start_date parameter inclusive, and then excludes all values on or after midnight on the day after the :end date.  If you were using actual timestamps, you could say  `+ INTERVAL 1 DAY` instead of `+ 86400`.

Comment: I tried using this approach, and bizarely I still get the exact same results! I just tried on for an 86400 second range ending on midnight the 14th of this month, and I still get results for the 14th returned.

I sent a start_date of 138430080, and end date of 1384387200, and one of the returned rows was 1384525509 - quite clearly not <= 1384387200.

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not know why, when I reversed the logic it worked perfectly.

```
WHERE timing.start_date < :end_date 
AND timing.start_date >= :start_date
```

This did not work however, and returned the same erroneous results.

```
WHERE start_date >= :start_date
AND start_date <  :end_date
```

Can Anyone explain why?

Comment: Make sure that the start_date and the end_date have the same format of time !